# Show that if $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ are independent random vectors, then $(X_1,Y_1,g(X_1,Y_1))$ and $(X_2,Y_2,g(X_2,Y_2))$ are as well.

Tags: probability, statistics, random

I am not sure how to go about showing that $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ being iid implies that $(X_1,Y_1,g(X_1,Y_1))$ and $(X_2,Y_2,g(X_2,Y_2))$ are iid for any measurable function $g:R^2\rightarrow R$.

This question is connected to a homework problem in which I'm trying to use the multivariate central limit theorem and the delta method to obtain an asymptotic distribution for the sample covariance - it's an intermediate step.

Comment: Didn't you ask this very recently on another page, where you received specific suggestions?

Comment: @Did I reworded the question to be more specific (just asking about independence). And I appreciated your specific suggestions however I believe I addressed them when I specifically stated that I could not find a reference defining independence of random vectors at the level that I can understand. Thanks for your contribution though!

Comment: What you call my contribution also solved the i.d. part. To reask the same question without even mentioning the previous episode is... well, suboptimal (to remain polite).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're referring to. I just remember you saying "Yes", which didn't really help me. Maybe I'm not aware of the etiquette of math stackexchange but the previous question seemed to have died (no more views accumulating, comments, etc) so I thought re-asking with more specificity might reawaken it. Anyway, sorry if I offended you or broached some unwritten rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ denote the underlying probability space and define $Z_1 = (X_1, Y_1)$ and $Z_2 = (X_2, Y_2)$.
Pick $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{B}^2$ and $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel sets. 
Then 
\begin{align}
P(Z_1 \in A_1, g(Z_1) \in B_1,Z_2 \in A_2,  g(Z_2) \in B_2) &= 
P(Z_1^{-1}(A_1 \cap g_1^{-1}(B_1)) \cap Z_2^{-1}(A_2 \cap g_1^{-1}(B_2)) \\
&=P(Z_1^{-1}(A_1 \cap g_1^{-1}(B_1))) P(Z_2^{-1}(A_2 \cap g_1^{-1}(B_2)) \\
&=P(Z_1 \in A_1, g_1(Z_1) \in B_1) P(Z_2 \in A_2, g_2(Z_2) \in B_2)
\end{align}
where the second equality follows because $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are assumed independent.

Comment: Are you aware of a way to do this without the language of measure theory? I haven't learned measure-theoretic probability yet..

Comment: Usually the approach which avoids measure theoretic language requires factoring a joint density or joint probability mass function into the product of its marginals. But since you didn't give any information about the distribution of the variables, can't really do that here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to read up on the measure theory and understand this proof. Cheers!